# rStudio: Clustering Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r

I'm working on some clustering with k-means. Once the code ist established, I want
to import data from an excel file. So the basic script works just well.

```
df <- USArrests  
df <- na.omit(df)  
df <- scale(df)  
head(df, top = 10)  
distance <- get_dist(df)  
fviz_dist(distance, gradient = list(low = "#33E3FF", mid = "white", high = 
"#80FF33"))
```

But if I export the rStudio training data to excel and reimport it back to rStudio,
 I end up with two errors:
1)

```
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

2)

```
Warning message:  
In stats::dist(x, method = method, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

So this is my script, which produces errors

```
df <- USArrests  
write.xlsx(df, "c:/my_path/USArrests.xlsx")  
df <- read.xlsx(file = "c:/my_path/USArrests.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)  
df <- na.omit(df)  df <- scale(df)  
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric  
head(df, top = 10)  
NA. Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape  
1    Alabama   13.2     236       58 21.2  
2     Alaska   10.0     263       48 44.5  
3    Arizona    8.1     294       80 31.0  
4   Arkansas    8.8     190       50 19.5  
5 California    9.0     276       91 40.6  
6   Colorado    7.9     204       78 38.7  
distance <- get_dist(df)  
Warning message:  
In stats::dist(x, method = method, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion  
fviz_dist(distance, gradient = list(low = "#33E3FF", mid = "white", high = 
"#80FF33"))
```

How can fix this? Or how do I import excel data for fviz_dist?

Edit:
Highlighting I how imported and export the data to excel:

```
write.xlsx(df, "c:/my_path/USArrests.xlsx")  
df <- read.xlsx(file = "c:/my_path/USArrests.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)
```

Comment: How do you export data to excel? How do you reimport data back to R? These are crucial steps here.

Comment: I used these lines:
        
    write.xlsx(df, "c:/my_path/USArrests.xlsx")  
    df <- read.xlsx(file = "c:/my_pathUSArrests.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Although its a bit late but hopefully you must have resolved the problem by now. Just thought to share my experience here so that someone can get a bit help.

```
1. Check your excel file if the data is exported properly. 
2. I prefer saving it as a csv (Comma Separated file) 
3. I assume that you are using Windows OS as you are trying to save in xslx file format. But do make sure to write delimiter as '/' or ',' at the time of writing the file.
```

Hopefully it will solve the problem.

Good luck